# How to represent Self join in Apache Metamodel using JdbcContext?

Tags: join, jdbc, self-join, apache-metamodel

Consider I have an `employee` table which has the following fields `id, name, email, phone, joining_date, manager, department`. Now in this table `manager` field can be used to create a self join and arrive at a result set which says **employee e1 reports to manager m1**. How do I represent this using `JdbcDataContext` and the `Query` POJO? Any pointers here will be much helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do self-joins just like any other join in MetaModel. Here's an example:

```
DataContext dc = ...
Table t = dc.getDefaultSchema().getTableByName("employees");
FromItem left = new FromItem(t).setAlias("e1");
FromItem right = new FromItem(t).setAlias("e2");
SelectItem id = new SelectItem(t.getColumnByName("id"), left);
SelectItem name = new SelectItem(t.getColumnByName("name"), left);
SelectItem manager = new SelectItem(t.getColumnByName("id"), right);
SelectItem managerName = new SelectItem(t.getColumnByName("name"), right);
DataSet ds = dc.query().from(left).innerJoin(right).on(id, manager).select(name, managerName).execute()
```